# Scala class with covariance in derivable type of parameter

Tags: scala, generics, types, covariance

I want this typeclass:

```
abstract class Model[U](val query: TableQuery[ModelTable[U]]) {
    // ...
}
```

But with covariance in the type of query.

The idea is that I have functions that take an instance of U, and need access to an instance of a corresponding TableQuery[ModelTable[U]].
Adding a type parameter is nasty, because I can no longer write functions using context bounds:

```
def f[U : Mode](u: U) = // ...
```

and writing out the implicit parameters everytime is quite hassle.
And as for now I cannot see why this would be impossible. Given a concrete type for U, the type constraint for query should be trivial to derive for the compiler.

Maybe more concrete: why can this not compile:

```
// error: Unbound Wildcard Type
abstract class Model[U](val query: _ <: TableQuery[ModelTable[U]]) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of an instance of the type class? I'm not sure I've understood what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Is this more or less what you are looking for?

abstract class Model[U, T <: TableQuery[ModelTable[U]]](val query: T ) {
  // ...
}

class TableQuery[T] {}
class ModelTable[T] {}

Comment: Yes, but as stated, an extra type parameter is not my ideal solution because now I cannot treat instances of model as instances of a typeclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `query` parameter is already covariant. It seems you have a problem like this:

```
class TableQuery[T]
class TableQuerySub[T] extends TableQuery[T]
class ModelTable[T]
class ModelTableSub[T] extends ModelTable[T]

class Model[U](val query: TableQuery[ModelTable[U]])

val x1: TableQuerySub[ModelTable[Int]] = ???
val x2: TableQuery[ModelTableSub[Int]] = ???
new Model(x1)
new Model(x2) // does not compile
```

Here `x2` does not compile with the following message:

```
type mismatch;
found : TableQuery[ModelTableSub[Int]]
required: TableQuery[ModelTable[?]] 
Note: ModelTableSub[Int] <: ModelTable[?], 
but class TableQuery is invariant in type T. 
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
```

Here the compiler tells us that it does not know for sure that `TableQuery[ModelTableSub[_]]` extends `TableQuery[ModelTable[_]]`. In order to tell the compiler that this is actually the case we need to make the parameter of the `TableQuery` covariant

```
class TableQuery[+T]
```

If this does not help you at all, please include the use case in your question.

---

**Edit**

Adding a second type parameter still allows you to specify a context bound. The context bound syntax is nothing more than syntactic sugar. The following statements are equal:

```
def f[U : Model](u:U) = {
  val m = implicitly[Model[U]]
  ???
}
def f[U](u:U)(implicit m:Model[U]) = ???
```

With this knowledge we can add a context bound for a context with more than one parameter:

```
class Model2[A, B]

def f[U](u:U)(implicit m:Model[_, U]) = ???
```

If you really want to specify it using the context bound syntax, you could do this

```
type AnyModel2[B] = Model2[_, B]
def f[U : AnyModel2](u:U) = ???
```

Without type alias you would get (in my opinion less readable)

```
def f[U : ({type T[x] = Model2[_, x]})#T](u:U) = ???
```

Comment: You are right about the parameter that the compiler complains about. I solved it as follows; `abstract class Model[U](val query: TableQuery[_ <: ModelTable[U]]) { ... }` which is allowed. But I'd be more interested as to the "why". Why are context-bounds limited to classes with one bounded generic, if these generics could be inferred by the compiler?

Comment: But maybe this requires more elaborate typelevel programming

Comment: Ah, thanks for the insight. I had not thought about the possibility of having a type alias with a wildcard. I think that is what I was looking for. I knew that context bound desugared to implicit, but as stated in the question: writing out the implicits is quite heavy. More so because I already have an implicit session passing around.